# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException:

Tags: java, swing, numberformatexception

```
public void chooseInterface() {

    int TEMP = Integer.parseInt(SelectInterface.getText());

    if (TEMP > -1 && TEMP < counter) {
        index = 0;
        Enable();
    } else {
        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Outside of
        // Range.#interface=0+
        // (counter-1)+".");
        System.out.print("dfdfg");
    }
    SelectInterface.setText("");
}
```

Error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
    For input string: ""
```

What is the problem in the code?  How to solve this error?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Consider using a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` instead of parsing text from a text field  4) The IDE is irrelevant to the problem, so don't add the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Check empty ("") values for

> SelectInterface.getText()

This will give NumberFormatException. Additionally, you can first check for empty value and replace with "0".